# How do you tell if a style is inherited?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

How do I tell if the value of a style is default, inline or inherited value?

For example, if I have a Label and I call getStyle("color") and it reports "#000000" how do I tell if that is a value it inherited or if it's a value set inline *at runtime*?

Comment: Might it be in the describeType() info somewhere?  If not; I assume you can't get this data.

Comment: If `describeType()` doesn't help, you might want to take a look at source for the StyleManager (actually, whatever class implements IStyleManager2). It has a method [isInheritingStyle()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/styles/IStyleManager.html#isInheritingStyle()) that you can use to test if a particular style is inherited. I've never looked into how CSS inheritance works in Flex, but you might start there... Do you just want to test one particular style or somehow find all the styles that a component is inheriting?

Comment: I want to test if one particular style is getting it's value from being defined inline like this, color="red", or if it's getting it's value from the parent container like this, container color="red". The method getStyle("color") gets the final eventual cascaded value. I'm curious to know how it came to be that value.